# Lookup and Transpose functions to return multiple values in a cell

Tags: google-sheets

I want to use a type of lookup function that will return a range of cells instead of one cell. Then transpose that data.

Typical Vlookup function

> VLOOKUP(Value_Lookup Range_Column_False)

I would like that column part to be a range in a row not a specific cell. For example:

> If the value exists with the defined range, send the values of the entire row the initial value is in. Then transpose the range in a selected cell.

Is there a way to do this? I am only familiar with the vlookup function, would Index Match work?

Here is a link to an example spreadsheet:
[Spreadsheet example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qG_p385O7L9nBVRlgmRB90go3wZmZVW9nkexvxGbtEM/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
=transpose(query(A1:EZ4,"select * where A ='Jimmy Medina' "))
```

---

Re supplementary, please try:

```
=transpose(query(A1:EZ4,"select * where A ='"&'Name Selection'!$A1&"' "))
```

Comment: This works out great! The cell that I am querying will be a random value and changes. How would I query the cell itself?

Comment: Yes exactly. The names will change, depending on what the user inputs. So the cell will have to be referenced. In the actually workbook, the user will select a name from a list that is pulled from column A in a separate sheet. Ive added a sheet called "Name Selection" to illustrate this. Once the name is selected, I would like to use that selection to tranpose the data relating to the name they selected to another sheet. Does that make sense? Thanks again!